# Not able to install MySQL on CentOS 6.6?

Tags: linux, centos6, yum

See the MySQL stautus on system.

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch

[root@n yum.repos.d]# yum remove mysql
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mysql
Package(s) mysql available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

After that i tried to install MySQL server- It gives some error message and fail to install.

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# rpm -ivh http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch (which is newer than mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch) is already installed
        file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql from install of mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo from install of mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo from install of mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch
[root@n yum.repos.d]# dir
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Vault.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  epel.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  epel-testing.repo
CentOS-Media.repo      mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
```

I am not able to insall the MySQL. How can I solve this issue and install MySQL 5.6 in my System. I am using remote system.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a package installed in your machine. You can use that one (which is a newer version than the one you are trying to install) or run:

```
rpm -e mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch
```

To remove it and then run the command you are trying to use.